# Insert an input variable in a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-modeler

I'd like to insert an input variable (integer) in a query SQL (@variable) using the algorithm `postgresql execute sql` in the graphical modeler of QGIS.

For example, in this kind of query

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = @variable;
```

where I should insert the variable in the input panel of the modeler and click play to do the query.
I used pre-calculated value but with no success. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build the SQL query, which should be a string. To do so, use a `pre-calculated value` and concatenate a string containing the query and the desired variable.

```
'select 1 + ' || @myval
```

[image]